# Snowflake: Trying to make a column to use as default the value from a sequence

Tags: sequence, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, I have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE_NAME (
  ID NUMBER(38, 0) NOT NULL,
  /* OTher elements */
)
```

With some values already (manually) inserted. I need to update this table so, for future inserts, the value of ID is taken from a sequence I just created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE S_TABLE_NAME_ID
START WITH 451;
```

For what I've seen in the documentation and in several forums, the syntax should be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER ID SET DEFAULT S_TABLE_NAME_ID.NEXTVAL;
```

But when I try to execute it, I get the following error message:

```
SQL Error [2] [0A000]: Unsupported feature 'Alter Column Set Default'.
```

Am I missing here something?

Answer (score 2):

from Snowflake Doc (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html):

> "To change the default sequence for a column, the column must already
> have a default sequence. You cannot use the command ALTER TABLE ...
> SET DEFAULT <seq_name> to add a sequence to a column that does not
> already have a sequence."

So I guess you have to set the sequence as column default when creating the table.

Comment: Seems right. It seems I'll have to create a new column (with the linked sequence), copy the values and delete the original column. Yay...